# How to create modal dialog using Vuejs and twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-transition

I want to create the input form dialog in [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/).

Is there any way, to create a bootstrap modal dialog using [twitter bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)?

I found a way (see below) to implement it but that needs custom CSS & I'm not able to pick bootstrap CSS.
[Example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html)

I can't use [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) or vue-bootstrap JS.

Comment: You could simply provide a link to bootstrap's css in their cdn in the head tag of your page

Comment: how can I avoid the modal-mask style. so no any custom css other then bootstrap css.

Comment: @user3711357 I could help you if you share your code with me...

Answer (score 0):

Use `bootstrap-vue`. Go through their documentation for [modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal) and you should be good to go.